# JQuery - Click selector not functioning on <i>

Tags: jquery

I've got this table cloning button which is supposed to disable itself after 4 rows are present and that works until I delete a row and want to add another, but it remains disabled.
So I attempted to make a selector to reevaluate the amount of rows and remove the disabled styling if it is below 4, however, the click selector is not functioning on my icon.

```
    $(function() {
        var i = 1;
        $("#addP").click( function()
            {
                i++;
                if(i > 4) {
                    $('#addP').css('cursor','not-allowed').css('opacity','0.65');
                    $('#warning').css('visibility', 'visible');
                } else {
                    $('#people').append('<tr><td><select name="title' + i + '"><option value="mr">Mr. </option><option value="mrs">Mrs. </option><option value="miss">Miss. </option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="forename' + i + '" value=""></td><td><input type="text" name="surname' + i + '" value=""></td><td><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o" id="delete' + i + '" onclick="$(this).closest(\'tr\').remove();" style="font-size: 30px;"></i></td></tr>');
                }
            }
        )

    });
    $(function() {
        $("i[id^='delete']").click(function() {
                alert("Test.");
                i = i - 1;
                i++;
                if(i < 4) {
                    $('#addP').removeAttr("style");
                }
            }
        )
    });
```

And because the append is quite confusing, I've formatted the innards:

```
    <tr>
    <td><select name="title' + i + '">
            <option value="mr">Mr.</option>
            <option value="mrs">Mrs.</option>
            <option value="miss">Miss.</option>
        </select></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="forename' + i + '" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="surname' + i + '" value=""></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o" id="delete' + i + '" onclick="$(this).closest(\'tr\').remove();"
           style="font-size: 30px;"></i></td>
</tr>
```

The button to add functions until I hit 4 rows as expected, but if a row is removed, it continues to block any additional entries.
Thanks for any assistance you can provide, and any modifications you make to my rudimentary (at best) JQuery skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 $(function() {

    $("#addP").click( function()
        {

            if($('#people tr').length < 4) {

                var i = $('#people tr').length;

                $('#people').append('<tr><td><select name="title' + i + '"><option value="mr">Mr. </option><option value="mrs">Mrs. </option><option value="miss">Miss. </option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="forename' + i + '" value=""></td><td><input type="text" name="surname' + i + '" value=""></td><td><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o" id="delete' + i + '"  style="font-size: 30px;"></i></td></tr>');

                $("#delete"+i).click(function() {
                    alert("Test.");
                        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                        $('#addP').removeAttr("style");

                })

            } else {
                $('#addP').css('cursor','not-allowed').css('opacity','0.65');
                $('#warning').css('visibility', 'visible');
            }
        }
    )

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MuWRW/

Comment: While it adds and deletes, the styling which says that you aren't allowed to add any more still remains and the alert, which signals the style is going to get removed, isn't fired , thanks for your help. Looks pretty good.

Comment: ok i have updated my answer you need to remove the onclick attribute of the i element

Answer (score 2):

See Yann86's answer. I'm simply elaborating on what is wrong in your code for your better understanding.

```
$("i[id^='delete']").click(function() {
        alert("Test.");
        i = i - 1;
        i++;
        if(i < 4) {
            $('#addP').removeAttr("style");
        }
    }
)
```

The `i` you are using here is not in the same scope as the one you are incrementing when adding a line. Nevertheless, you're doing some pretty weird operations there... first decrease by one, then increment again? Effectively does nothing.

Making `i` global would probably get your code to run. However, it is generally advised to make variables as global as necessary. Restructuring your code would work fine, i.e. remove the redundant call to `$(function(){...});` by merging the two functions together. Your variable could then just stay where it is right now.

Your code should look something like this:

```
$(function(){
    var i = 0;

    $("#addP").click(function(){...});
    $("i[id^='delete']").click(function(){...});
});
```

*the click selector is not functioning on my icon.*

*click* not a selector, it's an event. It's a shortcut method to `.on('click', listener)`. You'd get all messed up later on thinking that this would be a pseudo-CSS-selector. Let me give an example how:

```
$(function(){
    var $set = $('.row');
    $('#addP').click(function(){
        console.log($set.length);
    });
    $('<div>').addClass('row').append(document.body);
    console.log($('.row').length);
});
```

Imagine your HTML contains 4 predefined elements with the `row` class. This snippet would add another (empty) div with the `row` class to the end of your document, then print `5` to the console. When clicking the element with the ID `#addP`, you'd see `4` printed to the console. This is because `$set` contains only those elements that matched the selector when it was run.

Again, this is just for your better understanding of how jQuery works and not the best solution. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, although it wasn't the answer, it provided me with greater knowledge of JQuery. Thanks!

Comment: @PwnageAtPwn And that's all I wanted. ;)